# QT query.exec() returns always false

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite

I am trying to make a simple login form in QT, but I guess I am doing something wrong. I have watched a few tutorials, searched on different forums, and I couldn't find any solutions.

Database is declared like this:

```
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTSql>
#include <QtDebug>
#include <QFileinfo>

QSqlDatabase sqldb;
sqldb=QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE");
sqldb.setDatabaseName("data.db");
```

And started like this:

```
 if(sqldb.open())
    ui->label->setText("Conectat!");
else
    ui->label->setText("Nu m-am conectat!");
```

It looks like in my code, query.exec() only returns false.

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
user=ui->lineEdit->text();
qDebug()<<user;
if(!sqldb.isOpen()){
    qDebug()<<"Not connected to db";
    return;
}

QSqlQuery qry;

if(qry.exec("select * from users where name='"+user+"'"))
{
    int count=0;
    while(qry.next()){
        count++;
    }
    if(count==1)
        ui->label_3->setText("correct");
    if(count<1)
        ui->label_3->setText("not correct");
    if(count>1)
        ui->label_3->setText("duplicate");
}
else qDebug()<<"not working!";
}
```

If I change the if condition to !qry.exec(...) I always get "incorrect" message.
Any ideas?

Comment: How do you add database connection and opening? Provide the code for that part.

Comment: Does `sqldb.isOpen()` return true?

Comment: `"select * from users where name='"+user+"'"` **==> [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!!!**

Comment: @Nejat, problem is solved. It looks like I provided a wrong path for my database xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can usually find out what's wrong by using the [lastError()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#lastError) method of `QSqlQuery`:

```
if( !query.exec(...) )
{
    qDebug() << query.lastError().text();
}
```

Comment: It says: "no such table: users Unable to execute statement", but in SQLite manager I can see I have a table called users, and also the query works fine when used in sqlite3.

Comment: Nevermind, It looks like I provided a wrong path for my database. Thank you very much.